# Accessing resource/reference files from your final production program?

Tags: c#, file, excel, io, production

Please forgive me for my lack of C# knowledge!

How do I access a required file at run time if I don't know where my application is installed/exists on the hard drive?  Also- How do I distribute this file with my application (i.e., have it in a C:\Program Files\MyApp\resouces\file.ext)?

Background:

I'm using C# on .NET 3.5 with Spreadsheet Gears.  My program writes out a series of excel files based on the contents of a database.  One of the requirements is that the header in the page setup either needs to have an image or text with multiple colors/formatting.  I've looked into both methods extensively and found no solution for doing this programmatically. My fall back is to open a prebuilt excel file which already has the logo in the header (you can do this from within excel), place the data into the excel file, and save it under a new name in a user specified place.

Should I be looking into resources or opening pre-set template excel files?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users of your Application have the right privilege, I would go with using Registry object to query Registry. I might have misunderstood your question - I presume you are asking for a way to find the path of the application?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a way to find a file (reliably) which my program requires given that the program and file have been distributed to many users.

Comment: So I did misunderstand :-) apologies. You can do it this way:In your Project: (1) add the File that you want to be included into your .Net project (2) in the Solutions Pane, right click on the added file - choose properties (3) set the "Copy to Output Directory" option appropriately. This would ensure that your file will always be present in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: Right now I have the file located in `bin\Debug\resources\file.xls` - and I access the file via `string file = @"resources\file.xls"`.  When I add it to my solution, would I need to create a new directory called resources at the same level my solution is?

Comment: No. You must already be having a "Resources" folder under your Project. Go to Solutions Explorer, hover on the toolbars in Solutions Explorer window - you must see a Toolbar "Show All files". Make sure it is clicked. After this, you should be able to see the "File.xls" under your "Resources" folder in your Solution Explorer. It would appear with its outline dotted - just right click and choose "Include in Project". Now click on the Properties window and chose the "Copy to Output Directory". You will then need to refer to this file in your code WITHOUT any folder prefix (copies to output only).

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to make the name of the file relative, i.e. instead of:

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp\resouces\file.ext
```

have:

```
resouces\file.ext
```

and then have a small function that tries to open the file relative to the executable path, which you can get at run time. Don't open it based on the current folder as that can be different to the executable path.

Comment: When I distribute my program to other users, how do I make sure resources\file.ext gets put into place?  Also- when running from within Visual Studio, where is \resources\ on my file system? Under the Debug folder?

Comment: You use an installer, like Wix (http://wix.sourceforge.net/) where you can specify where files are put during installation. As for running in the debugger, that small function I mentioned can be made to look elsewhere, say, if DEBUG is defined then use a prefix something like "..\..\".

Comment: Does visual studio not have an installer built in?

Comment: @Joe: Maybe, the version I have has InstallShield LE and VisualStudio Installer. I have VS 2010 Ultimate. Wix is open source and created by some MS engineers and shouldn't have any limits on what it can create.